# unable to reload the page after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am trying to login using facebook JS, I am using the following code :

```
function FBLogin() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        //alert(response);
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'someurl.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'id=' + response.id + '&firstname=' + response.first_name + '&last_name=' + response.last_name + "&email=" + response.email,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
              setTimeout("window.location = 'otherpage.html'", 100);
            });
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus.reponseText);
          }
        });
        //window.alert(response.last_name + ', ' + response.first_name + ", " + response.email);
      });
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'email'
  });
}
```

In this I have a ajax call, I want to reload the page after the ajax success. In `someurl.php`, I am just echo some text, I want to `reload` the page after the ajax success.

I have tried

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    setTimeout("window.location = 'otherpage.html'",100);
    });
},
```

and

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  window.location.reload();
},
```

but none of code is working. Please help me. How can I reload the page when the ajax is successful?

Comment: remove   $(document).ajaxStop(function(){} for sure

Comment: your second approach should work fine. Do you see any errors ?

Comment: Tried placing `.ajaxStop` portion outside of, before `FBLogin` , `$.ajax()` call ? Do `FB.login` , `FB.api` each call `$.ajax()` ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla Sorry yar its not working

Comment: @mplungjan sorry not working

Comment: what errors do you see ?

Comment: no error ...... but not reload the page

Comment: Does `FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log(response);` show anything in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to a page using JavaScript, use this

```
location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
```

**NOT**

<strike>`window.location = 'http://www.example.com';`</strike>

Check it live [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/l10lv7h5)

Also, don't forget to add jQuery library to your page